# Android Screen Resolution for xlarge

Tags: android, screen-resolution

i developed an android appplication. and i want to test this application for xlarge screens.
when i tried to create an emulator with the following resolutions the emulators are not loading
is there any way to test the application for xlarge screens

**I tried with the following resolutions:**

```
hdpi-

     1536x1152

     1920x1152 

     1920x1200 




 xhdpi-

2048x1536

2560x1536 

2560x1600
```

my monitor is Dell-21" with resolution Max-1600*900.

Comment: Check: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: reduce the ram provided to the emulator to somewhere around 256MB. Its nothing to do with the resolution, you system is probably not able to allocate the requested memory to the emulator and so the emulator hangs

Comment: still it is not loading.and also i deleted all other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to test this application for xlarge screens. when i tried to
>   create an emulator with the following resolutions the emulators are
>   not loading is there any way to test the application for xlarge
>   screens

AFAIK you can Only create Emulator With Given Below suggestions with Density 
While Creating AVD you will get Below Image. you can only choose from the Below Devices to make your Emulator.

[image]

**Your Alternative Solution :**

> **However, I need to ensure everything's fine.**

Yes you can Surely get what you want.

if you want to Check whether your application runs perfectly on  960x640(Normal screen xhdpi) Device. you can Make Custom Configuration From Below Suggestion.

After Update your ADT to version 21.

**In Older Version each time you have to set `Add Custom` Screen if you want custom Device Configurations as (if you want Nexus 4).**

In ADT21 version you can get this thing done by

> **open `AVD Manager`, u can define your custom screen in `"Device Definition"`**

**Alternative (Much Easier approach)**

> in Newest Version you Don't Need to Set Custom Device
>   Configurations from the above Suggestion as much easier way is available for it. you >Just Have to Make Emulator With your Device 
>   Configurations and after you will see those Configurations with
>   Emulator Name Inside `Graphical Layout` of XML

like after Created my Emulator of Nexus7 Emulator with Android 4.2 with Name as "Nexus7_Android_4.2" i will get this Device Configuration in Graphical Layout of xml automatically.

Below is the Screen Shot of it.

[image]

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: An emulator can be defined with any resolution as per the requirements.The predefined device definitions are just to help you out with the standard resolutions and hardware specs.

Answer (score 1):

There are specific Android API calls that can, at runtime tell you what density and (small/large/normal) screen size a handset has. However, as a developer we should not need to worry about individual handsets at all. All we need to do is to have ldpi/mdpi/hdpi assets and small/normal/large layouts in the apk. Android internally handles everything.

Dont forget to get an indepth understanding of how Android determines which assets to use and aliasing [like this.](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

The definitions are:

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp.

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp.

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp.

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp. (Android does not currently support screens smaller than this.)

Here are some more examples of how this works with real screens:

A QVGA screen is 320x240 ldpi. Converting to mdpi (a 4/3 scaling factor) gives us 426dp x 320dp; this matches the minimum size above for the small screen bucket.

The Xoom is a typical 10” tablet with a 1280x800 mdpi screen. This places it into the xlarge screen bucket.

The Dell Streak is a 800x480 mdpi screen. This places it into the bottom of the large size bucket.

A typical 7” tablet has a 1024x600 mdpi screen. This also counts as a large screen.

Answer (score 0):

In emulator ie in AVD->Device Definition.You can select and fix any type of resolution. You

can also customise any type of size. Since it takes time to load due to high resolution in

emulator.

Comment: i created the emulator with the following sizes but that emulator is showing a blank screen it is not loading.

Comment: Start emulator from Android Virtual Device Manager